# Can't verify ubuntu 19.10 download on Mac os x

Tags: macosx, 19.10, sha256sum

Can't verify ubuntu 19.10 download on mac os: "gpg: can't open 'SHA256SUMS.gpg': No such file or directory gpg: verify signatures failed: No such file or directory"

Both the SHA256SUMS and SHA256SUMS.gpg are downloaded.

Comment: Please explain exactly what are You doing. Step by step.

Comment: I downloaded the SHA256SUMS and SHA256SUMS.gpg files from here http://releases.ubuntu.com/eoan/ and then ran the "gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS" Command according to this tutorial: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu?_ga=2.181286947.589493112.1574025654-340080257.1573670478#3

Comment: You are running it from a wrong directory. You need to run it from a directory where these files are located.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding **.txt** to the end so the command ended up looking like this **(gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg.txt SHA256SUMS.txt)**